# How to help an executable find a shared library?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ld, ldd

I'm trying to run [`RF-TrulyMagical`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rftrulymagical/), but it says:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried re-installing the library and running `apt-get update` and `ldconfig`, but nothing's changed. The library is at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and that path was already listed (I didn't add it myself) in a file inside the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory.
Output for `ldd RF-TrulyMagical` is:

```
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7fa1000)
    libSM.so.6 => not found
    libICE.so.6 => not found
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf7f6f000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf7e25000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7e20000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7e16000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7df7000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7c71000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7b6f000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7b51000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7973000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7fa2000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf7947000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf7943000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf793c000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0xf7921000)
```

Somewhere it said I should install `lib32-libsm`, but apt-get says `Unable to locate package`.

I have no idea what to do. Thanks in advance. (I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1, if that helps)

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get install libsm6:i386`?

Comment: @tink I'd tried to do that with libsm and it didn't find anything, libsm6 worked! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a simple case of:

```
apt-get install libsm6:i386
```